# Creating StreamWriter instances crashes the application with RPC error

Tags: c#, .net

I've stumbled upon extremely weird error. When using `FileStream` in the first `using` - application iterates through the loop and prints out "Done", however, then it `exits with the error code 5`. `Try/Catch` doesn't work either.

This seems to be extremely fragile error state because if I fiddle with the file names (for example `C:\TFS\file1.xml.No.xml` -> `C:\TFS\file1.xml.N.xml`) then it works fine.

If I use `var tw = File.CreateText` in the first using then the application `exits with the code 1073741845`. I've manage to reduce the problem significantly to just few lines of code below for a reproducible example.

Perhaps someone can explain why in the world this would behave so weirdly? I'm also interested in why I am not able to recover from this error state? I've tried `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` and `[SecurityCritical]` with no effect.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\TFS\file1.xml.No.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
            }

            using (var tw = File.CreateText(@"C:\TFS\file1.xml"))
            {
                ds.WriteXml(tw);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Pass {i} done.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Using .NET Framework 4.7 Console Application project.

**EDIT:**

If I put `Thread.Sleep(2000)` in each `using` statement - I then encounter this error after the 2nd pass - it prints `Pass 1 done.` and `Pass 2 done.` before `has exited with code 5 (0x5)` so the frequency of writing does not seem to be responsible for this behaviour.

Upon further tinkering with this small sample - I can reproduce the issue without  using `DataSet` at all and just with creating `StreamWriter` instances. The below example should produce before exiting abruptly:

```
TW1 created.
TW1 flushed.
TW1 created.
TW2 flushed.
Pass 0 done.


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            var tw1 = File.CreateText(@"C:\TFS\file1.xml.No.xml");
            Console.WriteLine("TW1 created.");
            tw1.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine("TW1 flushed.");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            var tw2 = File.CreateText(@"C:\TFS\file1.xml");
            Console.WriteLine("TW1 created.");
            tw2.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine("TW2 flushed.");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine($"Pass {i} done.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**EDIT2: **
So it appears for us this issue was caused by `Kaspersky Endpoint Security for Windows v11`.

Comment: Try moving your code out of Main and into a function called from Main. That might help with try/catch.

Comment: Is there any chance that you could have more than one instance of this running (file conflict) when you have problems?  Check taskman to be certain.

Comment: @tgolisch definitely just 1 instance at a time. Also moving into a function has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process exit code does not mean that much, you favor seeing the debugger stop to tell you about an unhandled exception.  But sure, this isn't healthy.  This is an anti-malware induced problem, they [don't like](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_Security_Cheat_Sheet) XML files.  Often a problem on a programmer's machine, they also don't like executable files appearing from seemingly no-where, created by a process that uses process interop like the IDE does to run msbuild.  Strong malware signals.  So first thing you want to do is temporarily turn it off to see if that solves the problem.

It surely will, next thing you'd do is switching to something a bit less aggressive. The anti-malware solution provided by the OS never gets in the way like that.  If you use Avast or anything else that has a "deep scan" mode then uninstall asap.

And worry a bit about what your user might use, getting an IOException from FileStream is quite normal so a try/catch is pretty much required.  In general you don't want to overwrite a file or delete a directory that you created milliseconds ago, luckily it is never a sensible thing to do.

Comment: I edited the sample code, it does not appear to have anything to with `XML` writes or the frequency of trying to write to file.

Comment: No real idea what the edit is supposed to prove, "file1.xml" still looks like an XML file to me.  But sure, just more evidence that this is caused by evil code you don't know about.  Thread.Sleep(2000) gives leeway but is no guarantee that it can scan the file quickly enough.  Use 60000 next.  And do follow my advice, temporarily disable it so you don't have to randomly putz with sleep amounts and drill down quickly to the most likely cause.  That's what we need to know to get you to the next stage.  Name the product you use as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for this. I was not convinced at first because we replicated this on multiple developer machines (but they are the same) as well as some server machines (which don't have UI terminals). You were right about the `Thread.Sleep(60000)` which yielded `IOException`. It was caused in the end by `Kaspersky Endpoint Security v11`.